# Synthesis of Colchicine

Tags: organic-chemistry

Recently one of my relatives have fallen ill and was prescribed with some colchicine. Looking at the structure of the molecule, and with nothing much to do, I decided to put my retrosynthetic skills to the test. Here is a picture of my thought process:
[image]

Is there a better way to design a synthesis for this compound using the disconnection method.

From **11b**, a Birch reduction is carried out to give the qunione **10b**. A rearrangement of the ketone with methanediazonium gives **9b**. A dihydroxylation with a peroxy acid and subsequent addition of water gives **8b**. A double dehydration reaction with sulfuric acid, coupled with the protection of the ketone with propan-1,3-diol gives the seven-membered quinone **7b**. A Heck reaction (or Ullmann reaction) with **7a** with a palladium catalyst yields **6**. (The protection group is thereafter labelled "PG") Friedel-Crafts acylation with ethanoyl chloride yields **5** (although on second thoughts, I should have done the acylation from **7a** from the start). A Michael addition is then carried out with $\ce{BuLi}$ to lithiate the ketone to give the terminal imine **4**. Since this terminal imine is unstable, a mild reducing agent converts the imine to the amine **3**. The ketone is then removed by addition of dithiol and subsequently reduced by Raney nickel to form **2**. Finally, a simple condensation reaction between the amine and acetic anhydride, followed by deprotection of the ketone using an acid, yields the final product colchicine, **1**.

Comment: While this is an interesting question I have to agree that it is too broad. Maybe focus on a specific aspect of the synthesis or head over to the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3229/the-periodic-table) to discuss your question in more detail.